# How to know if user came from google ads and understand that this is his n-th page in the session with JS code?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need to perform logic once a user that comes to the page through a context ad views n-th page in his session. 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sessions that land on the site from Google Ads have the **gclid** parameter in querystring.

From the site, with JS, you can check if that parameter is in the URL and insert a cookie that counts the pages visited. You can proceed with what you want when the session reaches the number of pages of your interest.